# "On the fly" projection ON by default?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS 1.6, can users set "on the fly projection" to be checked ON by default (at application launch)?  I know how to turn it on, but some users find they use it more often than not, and would like it to be enabled by default.

I have read [this thread](http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/363) and it seems like there was discussion to add an "ON by default" option, but I could not find it in the Options settings.

Is there something I am missing or has this function not been implemented?

Comment: I think you answered your own question by posting the link to the related ticket. The option is not implemented yet.

Comment: I kind of suspected that, but wasn't sure if someone more "in the know" had other info.  Any chance it will be implemented in the next release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but some users find they use it more often than not

I'am one of them.

A workaround:

-Start Qgis, set the reference system and enable 'on the fly'.
-Save the project on the desktop.
-Next time, 2x click that project.

Comment: I'd say that is as good of a workaround as I could think of.  I will pass it along.  Thanks.